# The multi-part identifier " " could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this stored procedure

```
Create Proc Get_Order_Production
AS

SELECT i.Name_Item
  ,[ID_Order]
  ,[Project]
  ,[Length]
  ,[Width]
  ,[Quantity]
  ,[Weight]
  ,[Supplier]
  ,[GDS_Name]
  ,[GDS_Date]
  ,[WorkshopName]
  ,[WorkshopDate]
  ,[ReservedQty]
  FROM OdredDetails od
   INNER JOIN ItemQuantity iq 
           ON iq.ID_ItemQte = od.ID_ItemQte 
   INNER JOIN item i
           ON i.ID_Item = iq.ID_Item 
   where [Order].Number_Order=od.ID_Order and [Order].[Location]='PRODUCTION'
```

When I execute I receive this error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_Order_Production, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 2]
The multi-part identifier "Order.Number_Order" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Get_Order_Production, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 2]
The multi-part identifier "Order.Location" could not be bound.
```

I try to use the original tables name and use parentheses but I failed

Comment: you not joining order table anywhere in join syntax

Comment: there's no order table in your query, should it be replaced with 'od' alias for 'OdredDetails'?

Comment: I would recommend adding the alias to every column in your query so you know what table the column belongs to.

Comment: @Ven is that a problem when i use it in where clause

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah query does not that order is a table unless u join it

Comment: @ avb no the order table is an other table

Comment: @Sean Lange i add it but i get the same error

Comment: Well of course you still get the error. You don't have that table in your query. You can't just randomly reference tables not in your query.

Comment: @Ven Thanks for your guidance i add join :                                                                                                                INNER JOIN [Order] ord
               ON ord.Number_Order=od.ID_Order                                                           where ord.[Location]='PRODUCTION'.now it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE `Join` syntax  , remove join from where clause

```
       SELECT  
    --column names 
       FROM order Inner join 
       OdredDetails od on [Order].Number_Order=od.ID_Order 
        --(it is orderdetails I guess)
        INNER JOIN ItemQuantity iq 
               ON iq.ID_ItemQte = od.ID_ItemQte 
        INNER JOIN item i
               ON i.ID_Item = iq.ID_Item 
         WHERE  [Order].[Location]='PRODUCTION'
```